# Java logs in Cassandra query run

Tags: java, logging, cassandra, cql

I wonder if I have there any log in the cassandra database system where I can see the underlying Java executions that run since I run a CQL statement until I receive the response from the command shell. If yes, how may I configure that?

EDIT (after Aaron answer): Well, the thing is I only see some INFO statements and many queries referring to system databases when I run fqltool as suggested after enable full query logging:

```
INFO  [main] 2023-05-05 21:27:21,876 Jvm.java:160 - Chronicle core loaded from file:/opt/cassandra/lib/chronicle-core-2.20.126.jar
INFO  [main] 2023-05-05 21:27:21,915 Slf4jExceptionHandler.java:44 - Took 8 ms to add mapping for /var/log/cassandra/fullquerylog/metadata.cq4t
INFO  [main] 2023-05-05 21:27:21,968 InternalAnnouncer.java:42 - Running under OpenJDK Runtime Environment 11.0.19+7 with 20 processors reported.
INFO  [main] 2023-05-05 21:27:21,968 InternalAnnouncer.java:46 - Process id: 3849
INFO  [main] 2023-05-05 21:27:21,971 InternalAnnouncer.java:59 - :: Chronicle Queue :: (5.20.123)
Type: single-query
Query start time: 1683304925138
Protocol version: 5
Generated timestamp:-9223372036854775808
Generated nowInSeconds:1683304925
Query: SELECT * FROM system.peers_v2
Values: 

Type: single-query
Query start time: 1683304925144
Protocol version: 5
Generated timestamp:-9223372036854775808
Generated nowInSeconds:1683304925
Query: SELECT * FROM system.local WHERE key='local'
Values: 

(+ MORE SYSTEM QUERIES DATA)
```

In my case, I did a GRANT ALL PERMISSIONS query with a WHERE clause which returned me a SyntaxException and I want to trace that in order to know what java Class is throwing that error.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable [query logging](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/operating/fqllogging.html), and then you'll be able to see them using the fqltool:

```
fqltool dump /tmp/cassandrafullquerylog
```

To enable this feature, [check the docs](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/operating/fqllogging.html#configuring-fql-in-cassandra-yaml) and locate the `full_query_logging_options:` setting area in the `cassandra.yaml`.  Or, you can enable it using nodetool:

```
nodetool enablefullquerylog --path /tmp/cassandrafullquerylog
```